# mosquitto: log message contents

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto as a MQTT-broker and I while it offers extensive logging functionality I can't find out how to log the actual topic's messages to a file (or even to a tree of files ordered by topic, or even a DB). I see the `log_desc topic` option but either it doesn't do what I expect it to do or it doesn't work (probably the first).

I know I can just subscribe to a (or all) topics on the same machine from another process and pipe that into a file and I know there is a solution to write the again client fetched data into a DB using python, but I want to know if the broker itself can write the data it channels somewhere, not just the metadata.

In the end I will probably need to write it to a DB anyway, but for now it would be fine to write the data into a tree of files, or even just a big logfile. Can the broker service do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the mosquitto broker will not log all the message content it's self.

The closest you can get is something like this:

```
1569256583: Received PUBLISH from mosq/F7RrCcwvgdVzEVpHi3 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'test', ... (3 bytes))
```

This includes the topic and the size of the message but not the message it's self.

It is important to remember that message content doesn't have to be text, it can be any bytes.

The `log_dest` flag is just where to write the log output, you set the level of logging with the `log_type` entry.

Comment: So the best practice here is to have another process subscribed and log that data? Because that seems like a sub-optimal solution to me, since it is hard to guarantee the subscribed process really gets everything...

Comment: With mosquitto your only option is a separate client, if it subscribes at QOS 2 then you can be confident that it will get all messages. Other brokers offer other options, e.g. HiveMQ has direct logging or Mosca will let you write your own

Answer (score 5):

I am also using mosquitto and wanted to log the messages of a topic.

First install mosquitto-client.
For Debian/Ubuntu that would look like:

```
sudo apt install mosquitto-clients -y
```

Then

```
mosquitto_sub -v -t "topic/name" > mylog.txt
```

More info can be found in the documentation:
https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html

Comment: How do I make this run right after mosquitto starts on boot? I tried putting it in cron under @reboot but that doesn't work. I guess it's because mosquitto starts after cron?